# When is a Lighthouse audit considered to be 'passed'?

Tags: audit, lighthouse

With the Google PageSpeed Insights tool now using Lighthouse audits, I am needing to update a WordPress plugin I built which puts these audits into the WP dashboard for users.

I've noticed that Lighthouse considers some opportunities to be 'passed' even if they do not score 100% on the audit.

Does anyone know if there is a fixed threshold that Lighthouse considers 'good enough'? For instance, maybe anything scoring 95% or better is considered a pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lighthouse returns a score between 0 (lowest possible score) and 100 (best possible score).

According to the [Lighthouse Scoring Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/v3/scoring#perf-color-coding):

> - 0 to 49 (slow): Red
> - 50 to 89 (average): Orange
> - 90 to 100 (fast): Green
>
> These color buckets were revised in Lighthouse [v3.1.1](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/releases).

Therefore, a "pass" appears to represent a score of 90 or greater.